# Decode base64 into jpeg and save the image to server

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

currently i have base 64 value in

```
$model->test
```

and i want to decode the base 64 value in controller and save it to database through API here some of my code in controller

i try to decode and cant figure out how to upload it to server and create path
however i try to to pass the $data to getinstance which is not working

```
public function doSaveStudent(StudentLoanForm $model)
{
    $url = API_URL . 'web/apply/student';
    $data1 = $model->test;
    $decode = base64_decode($data);
    $img = file_put_contents('webcam.jpg', $data);

    $model->doUploads();

    $ktpdetail = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image_ktp');

    $data = null;

    $data = [

        [
            'name' => 'univ_name',
            'contents' => $model->univ_name
        ],
            [
            'name' => 'test',
            'contents' =>$model->test
        ],

    ];
    // dd($model->test);
    if ($ktpdetail != null) {
        $data[] = [
            'name' => 'image_ktp',
            'contents' => fopen(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/') . $model->image_ktp, 'r'),
            'filename' => $ktpdetail->getBaseName() . '.' . $ktpdetail->getExtension()
        ];
    }

    if($ktpayahdetail != null){
        $data[] = [
            'name' => 'foto_ktp_ayah',
            'contents' => fopen(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/') . $model->foto_ktp_ayah, 'r'),
            'filename' => $ktpayahdetail->getBaseName() . '.' . $ktpayahdetail->getExtension()
        ];
    }
    if ($kkdetail != null) {
        $data[] = [
            'name' => 'image_kk',
            'contents' => fopen(Yii::getAlias('@frontend/web/') . $model->image_kk, 'r'),
            'filename' => $kkdetail->getBaseName() . '.' . $kkdetail->getExtension()
        ];
```

i expect to decode the base 64 and upload all the value using yii2 best practice

Answer (score 0):

The `yii\web\UploadedFile` is used only for files uploaded using file input in forms.

In your case `base64_decode($model->test)` should give you binary data of image.

Then you have two options what to do with them.

1) You can store them directly into BLOB attribute in database.

```
$imageModel = new MyImageModel();
$imageModel->data = base64_decode($model->test);
if(!$imageModel->save()) {
    throw new \yii\base\Exception("Couldn't save file to db");
}
```

2) You can save the file with `file_put_contents` and then store the path to file in your model.

```
$imageData = base64_decode($model->test);
//the used alias in path is only example. 
//The datetime and random string are used to avoid conflicts
$filename = Yii::getAlias(
    '@frontend/web/' . date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') .
        Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(5) . '.jpg'
);
if (file_put_contents($filename, $imageDate === false) {
    throw new \yii\base\Exception("Couldn't save image to $filename");
}
$imageModel = new MyImageModel();
$imageModel->path = $filename;
if(!$imageModel->save()) {
    //delete file if we couldn't save path into db to prevent creating an orphan
    unlink($filename);
    throw new \yii\base\Exception("Couldn't add $filename to database");
}
```

Comment: how about $imageModel = new MyImageModel();? From where it is declared (MyImageModel())?

Comment: That's just an example. I couldn't understand where exactly do you want to save your image from your code so i made an example ActiveRecord model to show how it is saved. You should use your real model instead of it.